# showing one div on image top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

i want to display a div on image top with some background color and there will be some data in it circular things indicates category and below it shows name and it's date https://jsfiddle.net/shane07861234/88k78f7n/2/ here is my try but can't able to incline them properly.Date and name will be displayed below category.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
<!-- <div class="box-hover"></div> -->
    <div class="image-div-contents">
        <div class="top-div">
            <div class="box-text"><span>AG</span></div><br><br>
            <div class="doc-name"> LLL Bill</div><div class="doc-date">2/02/2017</div>
       </div>
       <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
          <div class="validitity"><span>Validitity: Forever</span></div>
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="">
          <!-- <div class="box-tresc"><div class="circle-category"><b>Category:<b></div></div> -->
      </a>                     
   </div>
</div>
<!-- </div> -->
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM76h.png

Comment: Can you please clear your requirement.

Comment: @KiranPurbey i want have thumbnail of 200x300 and now i want to display and small div on image top as shown in fiddle with some data circular one and date and name of image.name of image and date will be displayed inline below circular category.but as shown it's no responsive and color of top-div class not showing.

Comment: Sorry, but still not clear. Just tell me what exactly you want. Whether you want the thumbnail image to displayed at top. or what?

Comment: @KiranPurbey no i want to hide some top portion of image and show the content.

Comment: Can you maybe draw a design of what you're trying to achieve? Your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @KiranPurbey see image i have added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you. your code was so messed up could not help more.

fair suggestion: do not use `position: absolute` and `float` until things can not be done easier way.

```css
.thumb {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  z-index: -1;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.thumbnail .img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 0 none;
}
.thumbnail {
  border: 0 none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.box-text {
  font-family: 'Aller Regular';
  z-index: 100;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 60px;
  top: 20px;
  -moz-border-radius: 30px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #652c90;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.image-div-contents {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.box-text {
  z-index: 4;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #652c90;
}
.doc-name {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: 'Aller Regular';
  z-index: 100;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: right;
  width: 90px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.doc-date {
  font-family: 'Aller Regular';
  z-index: 100;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  padding: 0px 90px;
  overflow: hidden !important;
}
.validitity {
  opacity: 0.8;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: 'Aller Regular';
  z-index: 100;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #ee3f6a;
  padding-left: 35px;
  padding-right: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.top-div {
  z-index: 1;
  /* position:absolute;  */
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #33FF99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
  <!-- <div class="box-hover"></div> -->
  <div class="image-div-contents">
    <div class="top-div">
      <div class="box-text"><span>AG</span>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="doc-name">LLL Bill</div>
      <div class="doc-date">2/02/2017</div>
    </div>
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
      <div class="validitity"><span>Validitity: Forever</span>
      </div>
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/400x300" alt="">
      <!-- <div class="box-tresc"><div class="circle-category"><b>Category:<b></div></div> -->
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- </div> -->
```

Comment: thanks inirectly it helps me and i improved my code too :)